# How do I autoload a class with the X Autoload module?

Tags: 7

I have [X Autoload](https://drupal.org/project/xautoload) installed and enabled. I'm trying to get a simple example to work. The below setup throws the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Pet' not found in
>   MY-SITE/sites/all/modules/foo/foo.module on line 15

Have I got the directory structure correct for pet.php? I'm finding the docs difficult to follow on the placement and naming of the file that contains the class definitions. I'm trying to follow the PSR-0 standard to begin with. Thanks.

**UPDATE: The below has now been corrected as per Clive's answer.**

foo.info

```
name = Foo
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = xautoload (>= 7.x-4.0)
```

foo.module

```
<?php

function foo_menu() {
  return array(
    'foo' => array(
      'title' => 'Foo',
      'page callback' => 'foo_page',
      'access callback' => 'user_access',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    ),
  );
}

function foo_page() {
  $output = \Drupal\foo\Pet::dog();
  return array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $output,
  );
}
```

Pet.php (MY-SITE/sites/all/modules/foo/lib/Drupal/foo/Pet.php)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\foo;

class Pet {
  public static function dog() {
    return 'Buster';
  }
}
```

Comment: To address the edit: see the last code block in the answer below. You need to use one of those two methods, currently you're half in-between both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file-system is case-sensitive, so is PSR-0. Try changing your class filename to

> MY-SITE/sites/all/modules/foo/lib/Drupal/foo/Pet.php

And make sure you're namespacing your class correctly, e.g.

```
namespace Drupal\foo;

class Pet {
  ...
}
```

Lastly, make sure you're referencing the class correctly in your module file. Either

```
// Top of file.
use Drupal\foo\Pet;

// In a hook or whatever
$dog = Pet::dog();

or

// In a hook
$dog = \Drupal\foo\Pet::dog();
```

Comment: Renamed to Pet.php, cleared the cache: same error. Should my class in Pet.php be named: `Drupal/foo/Pet` rather than just `Pet`?

Comment: Yeah, you need the right namespace or what's the point of using PSR-0 ;)

Comment: Working now. Thanks. So, basically this means I don't have to write `require "Pet.php";` before I create an object of the class 'Pet'. The method of including a .inc file with all the classes with the module's .info file seems more straight forward. I guess this comes into its own for much bigger projects.

Comment: Yeah you got it - it can be just as useful in smaller projects I've found